# PHP Disabling ipv6

Tags: php, ipv6

It seems that I need to somehow disable IPv6 on my php pages, but I am not sure how to do this.  I think I have to add --disable-ipv6 somewhere into my INI file... this doesnt look like proper syntax though.

I am trying to solve the following bug:
http://bugs.php.net/45519

Does anyone know where to put this?

Comment: I think this is something you specify at compile time, it's nothing to disable afterwards....

Comment: There could be other IPv6 problems though, e.g. http://www.businesscorner.co.uk/disable-ipv6-in-curl-and-php/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this is ancient bug and I doubt it cause anything in your case.

Comment: Good point. @Dave, what is actually happening to make you suspect there is a problem with ipv6?=

Comment: I am having this exact issue.  The URL exists... I can navigate to it but the funciton returns a 404 error.

Comment: @Dave it looks like more hotlink prevention than imaginable ipv6 issue. Actually 404 error has nothing to do with ipv6

Comment: What is hotlink prevention?  I also noticed that the url is 404ing on other php calls as well.  it is a JPG image and I can copy and paste it into my browser just fine.  Maybe i need to just delete this thread and start a more relevant one if this doesnt have anything to do with ipv6.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution to this not because of the bug, but because servers I'm contacting via PHP are seeing my IPv6 address and cannot respond.

Comment: Still, how do you disable ipv6 in php?  That's what the title of this is and people coming here are looking for this info.

Comment: Looking for the answer to the question as well.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've got the PHP source, disable IPv6 by configuring php with flag

```
./configure ...
      --disable-ipv6
            ...
```

Then proceed with the installation

```
make && make install
```

Check the correctness of the procedure by invoking phpinfo()

[image]